# MX Records help - Godaddy DNS

Tags: email, dns, godaddy

I am attempting to setup a email server. All my hosting is done on the same IP. I am new to MX Records and cannot seem to find anything that works.

My domain is registered and DNS is by GoDaddy.com.

Can someone please explain how must I setup my MX Records to point to same IP as my web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to point your MX record at a specific IP address, you first need an A record for it to point to.  As you have a web server, then you probably have one already:

```
 domain.com.  14400 IN A <ip address>
```

So your MX record would want to look like this:

```
 domain.com.  14400 IN MX 0  domain.com.
```

This says "Emails for domain.com should be delivered to the server with the IP address that domain.com resolves to".

It is often a good idea to create a separate A record for your email so you can separate email from the webserver down the track if you need to:

```
 mail.domain.com.  14400 IN A <ip address>
 domain.com.  14400 IN MX 0  mail.domain.com.
```