# DNS domain name not found sending email to postfix

Tags: email, dns, postfix

I'm in the process of setting up a postfix server on an EC2 instance to send / receive email.

I'm running into a series of problems, which I believe are mostly caused by incorrect DNS records.

I currently have my MX records setup with GoDaddy as follows

> [A record, Host: mail, Points to: Elastic IP address]
>
> [A record, Host: @, Points to: Elastic IP address]
>
> [MX record, Priority: 10, Host: @, Points to: mail.mydomain.com]

Where my domain.com is the domain for which I'm editing the DNS zone file. This configuration is based on [MX Records help - Godaddy DNS](https://superuser.com/questions/467121/mx-records-help-godaddy-dns) and [Ubuntu Postfix email account with forward](https://superuser.com/questions/467569/ubuntu-postfix-email-account-with-forward)

However, when I send an email to test@mydomain.com, I receive the following delivery error:

> Technical details of temporary failure:
>
> DNS Error: Domain name not found

I've setup a Unix user "test", but my guess is that the outbound mail isn't even resolving the mydomain.com domain name.

Any help debugging this DNS record issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the issue was not with the DNS records but with EC2 firewalls. Depending on the EC2 security group that you've placed your instance in, inbound / outbound traffic may be blocked on several of your ports (including 25, in my case).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

I opened port 25 to inbound traffic under the AWS EC2 dashboard and was able to successfully send / receive mail.